# How to put image to the cell randomly without JQ?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put randomly selected images to  5 cells.
How I can do this using only JS?

I have this table.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td id="00"></td><td id="01"></td><td id="02"></td><td id="03"></td><td id="04"></td><td id="05"></td><td id="06"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
        <td id="10"></td><td id="11"></td><td id="12"></td><td id="13"></td><td id="14"></td><td id="15"></td><td id="16"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td id="20"></td><td id="21"></td><td id="22"></td><td id="23"></td><td id="24"></td><td id="25"></td><td id="26"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What do you don't know? Generate the random number? Get a random id? Insert a random image? Generate a random image? What did you tried?

Comment: I want to take all id's and put to the 5 randomly selected cells my image.
So i don't know how to take all cells id's and selected only 5 from this group. :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w9bh3y5j/1/ like this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your question to clarify what you were asking.  It would help if you did that yourself by editing the post, rather than replying via a comment.  It would also help if you stated what you had tried so far.

Comment: Yes Adam. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is something like this:

First, figure out the five cells to put images in. To do this use a random number generator and five different variables, when a number is generated check to see that it hasn't already been assigned.

```
var firstNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*27);
var secondNumber= Math.floor(Math.random()*27);
var thirdNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*27);
var fourthNumber= Math.floor(Math.random()*27);
var fifthNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*27);
```

Secondly, get the id's of those cells

```
var pic1 =document.getElementById(firstNumber)
var pic2 =document.getElementById(secondNumber)
var pic3 =document.getElementById(thirdNumber)
var pic4 =document.getElementById(fourthNumber)
var pic5 =document.getElementById(fifthNumber)
```

Thirdly append the image.

```
pic1.innerHTML = "<img src='something.gif'/>'"
pic2.innerHTML = "<img src='something.gif'/>'"
pic3.innerHTML = "<img src='something.gif'/>'"
pic4.innerHTML = "<img src='something.gif'/>'"
pic5.innerHTML = "<img src='something.gif'/>'"
```

I delibrately left out the part where you compare the random generated number to each other to check to see if they were already used. If you need help with that let us know.

There are also lots of ways to improve this, you could for instance put all the variables in an array and loop through them. This is just meant to give you a basic idea of how to do it.

**After it was pointed out that there aren't 26 different options and the numbers don't climb sequentially here's another proposed solution:
Put all the possible id''s into an array and then do a random number generator with the length of the array as the max. Then you can match the random number to the index of the array.**

Comment: This will not work, there are not 27 different id's, there are only 17 and they are not in numeric order.

Comment: You could just to a check to see if the random number that was generated fits into one of the three ranges. If it doesn't generate another one, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Another option would be to put all the possible id''s into an array and then do a random number generator with the length of the array as the max. Then you can match the random number to the index of the array.